# calculate a row of numbers(see context for details)

Tags: algorithm

there are two rows of numbers, row 1 is consecutive numbers starting from 0, now ask you to fill out row 2 to make sure the number in row 2 is the times of correspoding number in row 1 appearing in row 2.

For example:

`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

`_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _`

To be more specific, we use `row1` for row 1 and `row2` for row 2, we fill out `row2` to make sure it satisies: `row2[i] = count(row2, row1[i])`. `count(row2, row1[i])` means frequency count of `row1[i]` among `row2`.

Comment: Do you want to generate all possible solutions for row 2?

Comment: @Jacob, there is only ONE solution.

Comment: This might be a problem for http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: There isn't only one solution.  M0=8, M1=1, M9=1 is a solution.  So is M0=8, M2=1, M8=1, and so on...

Comment: You say you want to solve this with code, which language? What have you tried? What errors are you getting? We don't write your programs for you, you do!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths.

Comment: What you are describing is known as a system of [linear Diophantine equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Linear_Diophantine_equations).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Look at the original question, whoever edited this makes it look impossible because they've taken out important information

Comment: @Josh: I didn't think I threw away anything important.  What's missing that changes the nature of the problem?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Oh, YOU edited it! Sorry, I'm just now rereading the original question and I realize that you were correct in your edit. I had thought the "Second Row" he was talking about was a constraint, not the answer

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, M0=8, M1=9, M9=1 meets these two equations, but it does not meet the question, M0=8 means there are 8 `0`s in row 2, now you have already consumed 3 spaces for M0, M1 and M9, and only 7 spacesleft for `0`.

Comment: @hiway I thought we were trying to find how many 0's, 1's,..., 9's there should be? Are we given the two equations AND the two rows? Or are we given the two equations and only the top row and we are looking to find the second row? I could have sworn I had this thing figured out a couple minutes ago...

Comment: Are there constraints on the values M* can take (it looks like they need to be in [0, 9])?  You need to find 8 more equations.

Comment: A more compact formulation is: find an array equal to its histogram (frequency count). Reminds me of this [XKCD comic](http://xkcd.com/688/).

Comment: @Josh, this question is an interview question, the original question just gives you the first row and ask interviewee to fill out row 2, to make sure numbers in row 2 are the times of corresponding number in row 1 appearing in row 2, and those two equations are not given, they are my ideas.

Comment: @hiway if the equations aren't given, what are we finding a solution FOR?

Comment: @Josh, the solution are the numbers we can put them in row 2, and they meet requirements. For this question, the solution is 6 2 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0, now I want to get this solution by programming, not by guessing.

Comment: @hiway yes, I understand now (after a few too many comments) that the second row is the solution, but my question is, if we're not given any equations, what are our constraints? What's to stop us from putting random numbers in the second row and calling it right?

Comment: While this question is slightly unclear, I do not feel it deserves negative votes.  In the second row essentially describes itself.  The first 6 means that it has 6 0s.  The 2 that follows means there are 2 1s.  The 1 after that means there is only 1 2.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth has shown you by example that the constraint `0*M0+1*M1+2*M2+...+9*M9 = 10` does not apply to this problem.  Please remove it from the description.

Comment: @Josh, there is only one constraint, I write it in code: row2[i] = count(row2, row1[i]). the `i`th number in row 2 equals the frequency count of row1[i] in row2. Hope you can understand it.

Comment: @hiway Ahh see that's what I've been looking for all this time!! Where is that little nugget in your question? I take it the trivial answer (all 0's) is not what you want? Is `6 2 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0` the only solution, or are there more?

Comment: @Josh, there is only ONE solution, if row2 are all `0`s, it doest not meets row2[i] = count(row2, row1[i]), let's say i is 0, row2[0] = 0, but count(row2, 0) = 10, 0!=10

Comment: @hiway Ahh I see you're right, that was stupid of me. If there is only one solution and you already have it, what are you asking for?

Comment: @Josh, I just guessed, now I want to get the solution by programming.

Comment: @hiway - The algorithm is: write a program to do the guesses for you.  There are only 42 possible guesses.

Comment: @mbeckish, if the numbers in row1 are from 0 to 1000, so how many guesses ?

Comment: @hiway I can't think of a way to do this without bruteforce, however, I reworded your question to hopefully make it easier to understand for others in the community more qualified than me (hopefully the edit will be accepted soon). Best of luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of 1000 runs this solution had to run the loop an average of 3.608 times

```
import random

def f(x):
    l = []
    for i in range(10):
        l.append(x.count(i))
    return l

fast = list(range(10))

while f(fast) != fast:
    fast = []
    slow = []
    for i in range(10):
        r = random.randint(0,9)
        fast.append(r)
        slow.append(r)
    while True:
        fast = f(f(fast))
        slow = f(slow)
        if fast == slow:
            break

print(fast)
```

f(x) takes a guess, x, and returns the counts.  We are essentially looking for a solution such that f(x) = x.

We first choose 10 random integers from 0-9 and make a list.  Our goal is to repeatedly set this list equal to itself until we either find a solution or run into a cycle.  To check for cycles, we use the Tortoise and the Hair algorithm, which move at 2 speeds.  A fast speed which is twice as quick as the slow speed.  If these are equal, we have run into a cycle and start from a new random scenario.

I ran through this a few times, and found the general solution for n>6 (where in this case n = 10).  It is of the form [n-4,2,1,0...,0,1,0,0,0]

Comment: Why not make it more general so that the "first row" can be from 0 to n? We've already found the single solution when n is 9.

Comment: The code is very easy to edit to work for other n; however, not all n have a solution.  For example, 6 does not.  I tested this on 12 and got the correct solution [8, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0].

Comment: +1^ it'd be interesting to see which numbers n produce solutions. Logically I'd think anything under a certain n wouldn't have any solutions (n=1, 2, 3...)

Comment: All n>6 have a fairly simple solution (I edited to add this solution).  n=4 has a solution of [1, 2, 1, 0], and n = 5 has [2, 1, 2, 0, 0].  n = 1, 2, 3, or 6 have no solutions

Comment: I missed another solution for n=4: [2,0,2,0].  I believe n=4 is the only number with more than 1 solution.  At least it is for all n < 50

Comment: @user1125600, it seems that given any random `fast`, it always run into a cycle, why ?, and I have only found out these three cycles: `[7, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]`, `[6, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]`, `[6, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]`, why only these three cycles ?

Comment: @hiway, With a set of finite x, and any f(), repeatedly performing x = f(x) will eventually run into a cycle. There are only finite possible x, you will eventually run into any given x twice (unless you run into a cycle before that). The second time will behave exactly the same as the first and thus you will be in a cycle.  As for why those are the only 2 cycles, it is simply an observation but I will do my best to explain:  f(x) essentially takes a guess x and returns a new better guess.  This makes it extremely unlikely that any cycles will happen far from the solution, and likely few occur

Answer (score 3):

We can solve this mathematically.

Let's call our solution `s`, and `p` the subset of `s`, where `s[i] > 0`, that is, the set of represented numbers (any zero is a number or index that is not represented).

We can say that `n = sum of all frequencies = sum p`

Now let's call `p'` the subset of `p` without `s[0]`, which are frequencies only of numbers greater than zero.

Clearly `sum p' = sum p - s[0] = length p`, which is simply the count of how many numbers in `s` are greater than zero.

Remember that `length p = length p' + 1`. Now if `length p > 4`, we know that `sum p' > 4` and we are left with an `m` length partition (`p'`) that must sum to `m+1`, where `m > 3`. The only way this can be done is with `(m-1)` 1's and one 2, e.g., `[1,1,1,2]` in the case of `m=4` (by definition there are no zeros in `p'`). Such a partition could not make sense as a solution to our problem, and so we see that `p`, or the subset of numbers greater than zero in our solution, must have less than 5 elements.

Now we can solve for specific cases:

Every solution must have `s[0] > 0` since a zero in the zero column would invalidate the solution.

`length p = 1` would only be possible if `s[0]` could be both zero and greater than zero at the same time.

`length p = 2` implies `p' = [2]`, and so there are two zeros and two 2's, `s=[2,0,2,0]`

`length p = 3` implies `p' = [1,2]`. Since we know there is only one more `s[i]`, which is `s[0] > 0`, the 2 in `p'` must either refer to itself, in which case we have `s=[2,1,2,0,0]`; or to two 1's and therefore `s=[1,2,1,0]`

`length p = 4, p' = [2,1,1]`. In this case the 2 could only be referring to the two 1's and we must assume `s[0] > 2`, which also means `sum p >= (3+2+1+1 = 7)`. This  is the final / general case that user1125600 found: `s[1]=2, s[2]=1`. The last 1 refers to `s[0]` and so its index equals `s[0]`. Remembering that `sum p - s[0] = length p`, we get, `s[0] = n - 4`, and the solution, for p = 4, n > 6: `s=[n - 4,2,1...1,0,0,0]`

Comment: how do you conclude that: `sum p'= length p` or `sum p -s[0]=length p` ?

Comment: I understand now, `sum p'` is `n` minus frequencies of `0`, that is just `length p`

Comment: Does `p = 2` mean `p` is the set containing the single element `2`, or `p` is a set of two elements?

Comment: @aschepler good point, it's the length (a set of two elements), sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: brute force.  There are only 42 [integer partitions of 10](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integer+partitions+of+10).  Try them all and see which one works.