# Give random integers and a transform function, after some times of transformation, it will run into a cycle

Tags: algorithm

This is a derived question, you can refer to [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824101/calculate-a-row-of-numberssee-context-for-details), 
and my question is: Given 10 random integers(from 0 to 9, repeating allowed), and a transform funciton `f`, `f` is this(in python 3.3 code):

```
def f(a):
    l = []
    for i in range(10):
        l.append(a.count(i))
return l
```

Supposing `a` is the ten random integers, execute `f` and assign the result back to `a`, repeat this process, after a few times, you wil run into a cycle.
It is to say: a, a1=f(a), a2=f(a1)..., there is a cycle in this sequence.

test code is as following(code from @user1125600):

```
import random
# [tortoise and hare algorithm][2] to detect cycle
a = []
for i in range(10):
    a.append(random.randint(0,9))
print('random:', a)
fast = a
slow = a
i = 0
while True:
    fast = f(f(fast))
    slow = f(slow)
    print('slow:', slow, 'fast:', fast)
    i +=1
    # in case of running into an infinite loop, we are limited to run no more than 10 times
    if(i > 10):
        print('more than 10 times, quit')
        break
    if fast == slow:
        print('you are running in a cycle:', fast, 'loop times:', i)
        break
```

how to prove why existing a cycle in it ? And another interesting thing is that: look at the results of test, you will find that `fast` and `slow` will meet only at three points:`[7, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]` and `[6, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]` and `[6, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: While you've described it in terms of code, this is fundamentally a question about mathematics, not programming. Try asking on http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: For `a = [6, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]`, `a == f(a) == f(f(a)) == ...`. Any permutation of those digits also maps to `a`.

Comment: There are essentially only 2 cycles.  f([7, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]) = [6, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]  and f([6, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] ) = [7, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0].  Those 2 make up 1 cycle, and [6, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] is it's own cycle.  Additionally, there is no need for the break if more than 10 times, because the only way to run into an infinite loop is if you run into a cycle, which is already tested for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has to be a cycle because `f` is a function (it always produces the same output for a given input), and because the range of the function (the set of possible outputs) is finite. Since the range is finite, if you repeatedly map the range onto itself, you must eventually get some value you've already seen.

Comment: Furthermore, if the transform function `f` is bijective (invertible), you will eventually get back *the value you started with* (a stronger statement). Poincaré's recurrence theorem, for reference.

Comment: @Thomas: true, but this function isn't bijective.

Comment: Which is why it's a comment :]